# Phantom borders Table inside table Css

Tags: html, css

I have a table within a table and there are these phantom borders. For the life of me I have tried so many things to kill these extra spaces and I do not know how to get rid of them.  Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQfea/1/)

```css
body{
    background: #ddd;
}
.outterTbl{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    background: green;
}
.outterTbl th{
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
.outterTbl td{
    margin: 0px; 
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border: none;
}
.innerTbl{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.innerTbl th{
    background: #3399cc;
    color: white;
}
.innerTbl tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: white;
}
.innerTbl tr:nth-child(even){    
    background: #9ccde5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding

```
padding: 0px;
```

to the outertable td does the trick

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VQfea/3/)

Comment: Damn how the heck did that work for you... I tried so many different combos of 0px padding, margin, border-spacing.  Thank you!